# Dissolving NaOtBu in toluene

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I am conducting a synthesis using Buchwald-Hartwig coupling, and many reaction conditions use NaOtBu and toluene. Also the internet says that the solubility of NaOtBu in toluene is 130 g/L at 20 ℃. I only use 42 mg of NaOtBu and 5 mL of toluene, but toluene doesn't readily dissolve NaOtBu. Due to this, NaOtBu powder sticks to the wall of reaction flask as I start stirring. And these powders that sticked to the wall does not dissolve in toluene again. As a trial, I weighed same amount of NaOtBu in vial, and added 5 mL of toluene. I stirred it for 2 hours, but still there are some powders that stick to the wall, and the toluene seems like suspension, not clear solution. Is this a natural phenomenon? In this situation, can I say that I added NaOtBu properly in the toluene? Currently, I weigh all the reagents in the solid powder form and put them into the reaction flask, then add anhydrous toluene by syringe.

Comment: How are you storing your NaOtBu? Is it kept in a desicattor? It will pick up water readily giving NaOH and tBuOH

Comment: @Waylander Yeah, I also blow Ar gas before sealing the NaOtBu. When I searched for it NaOtBu readily reacts with water, and in fact it released gas when I dropped water. So I think that the storage is not the problem.

Comment: How well does the reaction work using the NaOtBu as you have done?

Comment: Note the solubility of NaOtBu in toluene is 2.27g/100g which equates to about 19.5g/L so your 5ml of Toluene should still dissolve 42mg of NaOtBu

Comment: @Waylander I am still testing whether the reaction goes on varying the reaction conditions. As far as I know dissolution of NaOH is exothermic, but gas evolution is not observed prominently, therefore I concluded NaOtBu was not converted to NaOH during storage.. But undissolving NaOtBu is somewhat strange.

Comment: Well, that it's soluble doesn't mean it has to easily dissolve. Maybe heat it.

Comment: @Mithoron I am conducting my synthesis at 80 celsius degree, but refluxed toluene does not wash away the powders that sticked to the wall..

Comment: When running these reactions I never paid much attention to whether the NaOtBu went into solution, the reactions worked whatever.

Comment: Have you tried making your own reagent from sodium and HOtBu in refluxing toluene to assure that the sodium is liquid?

Comment: @Waylander Another person who have conducted this reaction said so. Maybe that really doesn't matter significantly. Thank you.

Comment: @user55119 I have not tried that, but dealing with metal sodium seems quite difficult.. I'll consider it.

Comment: Handling metallic sodium is not a problem. Cut it with a knife under dry, inert solvent such as pentane or hexane.. Handle pieces with tweezers. Weigh in an inert solvent.